# How do I make sure that the client is using (or able to use) TLS v1.2 while visiting some pages of an application?

Tags: java, ssl, httprequest, tls1.2, sslcontext

I am working on a credit card support module on a Java-based Web application, for security, we want to have the users use TLS v1.2 supported browsers while viewing  the credit card pages 
How do I make sure they are compatible?
Note: We don't want to restrict users to other pages if they are not compatible.

Comment: Is this a Spring app?

Comment: @Dan yes, this is spring based.

Comment: @Andreas: I have changed my question, and this question is not a Duplicate. The other question doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You can write a filter and somehow access https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getProtocol() to programatically verify the page and the session's TLS version.

Comment: Link to duplicate "[How to force java server to accept only tls 1.2 and reject tls 1.0 and tls 1.1 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466407/5221149)" removed

Comment: @rodrigoap Please explain how do I get session's TLS version from the session/request object? Thank you for all the help here.

Comment: Not sure this is a great idea?  Session can be compromised at lower encryption in advance of reaching the secure area.  If attacker can compromise in advance, then they can run MITM, establish TLS 1.2 with server, and maintain lower, compromised encryption with victim user.  Not sure your usecase, so not sure if this applies, but be careful when being "clever" with encryption, lots of alpha-nerds puts tons of work into devising current schemes, getting "creative" with them is perilous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question. Here's some information

[How do I detect the TLS version of an HttpServletRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813852/how-do-i-detect-the-tls-version-of-an-httpservletrequest)

[Can I detect the SSL version that a browser supports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896708/can-i-detect-the-ssl-version-that-a-browser-supports)

https://gist.github.com/SamuelChristie/13a2a29e74c189bcfd9b   - Gracefully Deprecating TLS 1.0

Comment: thanks, @John. We have an f5 server and we will be adding a header variable so that we could check the same while loading the page.
For future views to this page: 

This is the code:
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  HTTP::header insert X-SSL-Protocol [SSL::cipher version]
  HTTP::header insert X-SSL-Cipher [SSL::cipher name]
}